# Having trouble downloading Android SDK platform-tools

Tags: java, android

I cd into my `opt/android-sdk-linix/tools` and run `./android` and attempt to download the tools, but I get this
changing permissions of `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator': Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

You should try running it with `su` rights

Comment: can you break that down for me? how would i go about that? still getting my feet wet with linux, any help would be awesome @chopchop

Comment: try typing `su ./android`. It should ask for the admin password

Comment: when i typed `su` i got `authentication failure`

Comment: i get `unknown id: ./android`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to donwload the platform tools is by visiting this site it helped very well .You will find all the platforms and evrything http://www.hariadi.org/android/manually-download-of-android-sdk-tools-and-sdk-platform-tools/

Comment: All you have to do is download the packages and install them manually. Its the best way to download them, because I remember very well I had a heck of a hard time setting that up using the android download manager!

Comment: im having trouble with the permissions though, i cant extract anything in my android-sdk-linux file